# Responsive javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

Can anyone please help with a dodgy if statement, try as I might I can't see anything wrong with it, the code works when outside of the if statement:

```
var sizeBefore;
var sizeAfterResize;
var sizeBreakPoint;
var resizeTimer; 
$(function() {
    sizeBefore = $(window).width();
    sizeBreakPoint = 500;
    doneResizing();       
});

function doneResizing(){
       sizeAfterResize = $(window).width();
       if ((sizeBefore < sizeBreakPoint) && (sizeAfterResize >= sizeBreakPoint)) {
                alert('Before:' + sizeBefore);
                alert('After:' + sizeAfterResize);
                sizeBefore = sizeAfterResize;
                // THIS RUNS WHEN OUTSIDE IF STATEMENT
       }
}


$(window).resize(function() {
    //doneResizing();
     clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
     resizeTimer = setTimeout(doneResizing, 100);
});
```

EDIT: This statement should only be true on both document ready or completion of resize when the window has been resized from smaller than `sizeBreakPoint` to larger than `sizeBreakPoint` - hope this clarifies

EDIT: SOLUTION

```
var sizeBefore;
var sizeAfterResize;
var sizeBreakPoint;
var resizeTimer; 
$(function() {
    sizeBefore = $(window).width();
    sizeBreakPoint = 500;
    doneResizing();       
});

function doneResizing(){
       sizeAfterResize = $(window).width();
       if ((sizeBefore < sizeBreakPoint) && (sizeAfterResize >= sizeBreakPoint)) {
                alert('Before:' + sizeBefore);
                alert('After:' + sizeAfterResize);
       }
       sizeBefore = sizeAfterResize;
}


$(window).resize(function() {
     clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
     resizeTimer = setTimeout(doneResizing, 100);
});
```

Comment: Why is `$(function() {
    sizeBefore = $(window).width();
    sizeBreakPoint = 500;
    doneResizing();       
});` wrapped in JQuery?

Comment: @howderek Isn't that the same as doing "$(document).ready"?

Comment: If it works out of the if statement, my guess is that the if rules are wrong. Have you console.logged values of the if, to make sure you're going into the if?

Comment: Jep, `$.ready()` and `$(function)` are semantically the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok from looking and testing your if i can say:

```
if ((sizeBefore < sizeBreakPoint) && (sizeAfterResize >= sizeBreakPoint))
```

this is only true if your window starts with smaller then 500 and after you resize if it goes over 500. This because you never change you sizeBefore other then on page load.

Can you tell me what you really want to verify? Or if this what you really want.

** edit: suggested solution **

try to do something like this:

```
$(function() {
   sizeBreakPointMin = 480;
   sizeBreakPointMax = 520;
   doneResizing();       
});

function doneResizing(){
   sizeAfterResize = $(window).width();
   //this way you have a window where this is false and it's as you want to allow the window as in a fine size
   //you can garantie that the window is always bigger then 480 and smaller then 520
   if ((sizeAfterResize < sizeBreakPointMin) || (sizeAfterResize >= sizeBreakPointMax)) {
            alert('Before:' + sizeBefore);
            alert('After:' + sizeAfterResize);
            // THIS RUNS WHEN OUTSIDE IF STATEMENT
   }
}
```

from your code:

```
 if ((sizeBefore < sizeBreakPoint) && (sizeAfterResize >= sizeBreakPoint)) {
            ...
            sizeBefore = sizeAfterResize;
 }
```

this two lines don't go well together because the first time this is true you just garantied that `sizeAfterResize >= sizeBreakPoint` making the next time you go check the if `sizeBefore` is will always be bigger then `sizeBreakPoint` making the if statement impossible to enter 2 times as it is (and if you don't change `sizeBefore` outside the if.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the aim is to check both on page load and on completion of resize if the window width is smaller or greater than the break point and execute the relevant code. This needs to work if the window is resized multiple times. Once there's a working example I'll implement a version which only runs if the browser is wider than the 500 breakpoint.

Comment: @JonChubb try to change the `&&` to a `||` That way if the the window is small it does the alerts OR if the the current size is bigger it does the alerts

Comment: @JonChubb there is problem, they way you are verifying it is always true. you have to give diferent break points one smaller and another bigger. This way will say that if the window is outside does points its to big or to small. Do you understand what i mean? i'm going to update my answer with a suggestion to this.

Comment: you are right I moved the `sizeBefore = sizeAfterResize;` after the if statement and it now works great - I'll update the initial question with the solution should anyone else need similar code. Many thanks for al your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem lies within the if condition.
`sizeBefore` is whatever your screen width is at the document ready event, which if you have a fullscreen browser, will be bigger than 500 (which is your breakpoint value). But you're never updating the `sizeBefore`, so it will never be lower than the `sizeBreakPoint`, and so, this part of the if statement will never be true: `(sizeBefore < sizeBreakPoint)`

Comment: I think you're right, the statement works if the browser is smaller than 500 on document ready but will not work afterwards. How do I make the `sizeBefore = sizeAfterResize;` statement work - I take it that is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is no direct answer to the question, just my own twist on a responsive `JavaScript`

```
// calculate viewport width so that we can load js conditionally
function responsive(){
    var scaffolding = 'desktop';
    var w = parseInt($(window).innerWidth(), 10);
    if (w > 0 && w < 768) { scaffolding = 'phone'; }
    if (w >= 768 && w <= 980) { scaffolding = 'tablet'; }
    if (w > 980) { scaffolding = 'desktop'; }
    return scaffolding;
}

if ( responsive() == phone ) {
    // do stuff only on phones
}
if ( responsive() != phone ) {
    // do stuff everywhere else but phones
}
```

You get to define what each breakpoint represents and what it is called, in a way that it still makes sense when you start using the condition later in the code.